# How to hide a UIPopoverController while a lengthy operation is to be performed?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

After selecting an option from a popover controller, the delegate is informed that a selection has been made.

I want to dismiss the popover, have it removed from the screen, and display an activity indicator to the user.

Unfortunately, the code below the dismissPopover runs before the popover actually disappears, resulting in a long wait without anything appearing to be happening.

```
- (void)itemSelected:(int)option {

    [popController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    switch (option) {
        case 0:
            // Do something that takes some time
            break;

        case 1:
            // Do something that takes even longer
            break;
    }

}
```

What's the best way to return control back to the calling ViewController after dismissing the popover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you change the UI, it doesn't happen instantly.  The changes are actually queued up to occur next time the main event loop finishes.  Since that usually happens right away, we usually don't have to worry about the difference.  All UI updates happen on the main thread, and since your long operations are also on the main thread, the app never gets around to updating the UI until the long operations are done.

One solution would be to use Grand Central Dispatch to offload those operations to another thread, which will allow the main thread to continue executing (and the UI to continue updating) until the operation is done.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [self performReallyLongOperation];
});

dispatch_release(queue);
```

Comment: I have a long running operation that must run on the UI thread. Are you aware of any way to dismiss the popover before starting the long running operation. Starting the long running operation with dispatch_asyc on the main thread results in the same behavior as the OP reported.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  The way UIKit is set up, if you're running code on the main thread, it won't reach the end of the event loop and update the UI.  You'll have to re-examine your algorithm for the parts that can be offloaded to another thread.  If the UI needs to be updated while this is in progress, you could use notifications or some other sort of hook to periodically make those updates.

Comment: Did some experimentation and you can get the desired effect by wrapping the asynch call in an dispatch_after block (wait 100ms or so)... This effectively delays the asynch functionality for enough time for the popover to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIPopOverController's delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPopoverControllerDelegate/popoverControllerDidDismissPopover%3a) method `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` to execute your code after the popover is done dismissing:

Header

```
<UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

Implementation

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    switch (option) {
        case 0:
            // Do something that takes some time
            break;

        case 1:
            // Do something that takes even longer
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: tried that, but because the popover is being dismissed programatically (i.e. the selection is made by the user within the popover), the popoverControllerDidDismissPopover message is not raised.

Comment: @Bill +1 That's interesting. Sorry I couldn't be more help!